# Split pandas series of '_'-separated string into variable number of fields, filling missing fields

Tags: python, pandas, split

In the following dataframe I would like to properly split the series 'resource' in its different components natively separated by the character '_':

| resource |
| --- |
| MTUG1_ABO_DPP_1 |
| MTUG1_ABO_DPP_2 |
| MTUG1_ABO_DPP_3 |
| MTUG1_ABO_DPP_4 |
| MTUG1_ABO_DPP_5 |
| MTUG1_ABO_DPU_1 |
| MTUG1_ABO_DPU_2 |
| MTUG1_ABO_DPU_3 |
| MTUG1_ABO_UUB_VDU1_1 |
| MTUG1_ABO_UUB_VDU1_2 |
| MTUG1_ABO_UUB_VDU1_3 |
| MTUG1_ABO_UUB_VDU2_1 |
| MTUG1_ABO_UUB_VDU2_2 |

```
import pandas as pd
Data = {'resource':['MTUG1_ABO_DPP_1','MTUG1_ABO_DPP_2','MTUG1_ABO_DPP_3','MTUG1_ABO_DPP_4','MTUG1_ABO_DPP_5','MTUG1_ABO_DPU_1','MTUG1_ABO_DPU_2','MTUG1_ABO_DPU_3','MTUG1_ABO_UUB_VDU1_1','MTUG1_ABO_UUB_VDU1_2','MTUG1_ABO_UUB_VDU1_3','MTUG1_ABO_UUB_VDU2_1','MTUG1_ABO_UUB_VDU2_2']}
df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns= ['resource'])
```

The result I want is:

| Node | Unit | unit_num | vdu_num | vm |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MTUG1 | DPP | 1 |  | DDP_1 |
| MTUG1 | DPP | 2 |  | DPP_2 |
| MTUG1 | DPP | 3 |  | DPP_3 |
| MTUG1 | DPP | 4 |  | DPP_4 |
| MTUG1 | DPP | 5 |  | DPP_5 |
| MTUG1 | DPU | 1 |  | DPU_1 |
| MTUG1 | DPU | 2 |  | DPU_2 |
| MTUG1 | DPU | 3 |  | DPU_3 |
| MTUG1 | UUB | VDU1 | 1 | VDU1_1 |
| MTUG1 | UUB | VDU1 | 2 | VDU1_2 |
| MTUG1 | UUB | VDU1 | 3 | VDU1_3 |
| MTUG1 | UUB | VDU2 | 1 | VDU2_1 |
| MTUG1 | UUB | VDU2 | 2 | VDU2_2 |

So, **MTUG1**--> becomes the content of a new column 'Node'
**DPP**  **DPU**  **UUB**--> become content for the new column 'Unit'
Then I need to build another new series 'vm' where I concatenate the string in 'Unit' with the next number (separated by adding '_') and if the content in 'unit_num' is VDUx I need to concatenate it also with a fifth part which is vdu_num.

But if I use:

```
df['Node']=df['resource'].str.split("_").str.get(0)
df['Unit']=df['resource'].str.split("_").str.get(2)
unit_num=df['resource'].str.split("_").str.get(3)
vdu_num=df['resource'].str.split("_").str.get(4)
df['vm']=df['Unit'].str.cat(vm_num, sep="_").str.cat(vdu_num, sep="_")
df['vm'].unique()
```

I get only the VDU components:

```
array([nan, 'UUB_VDU1_1', 'UUB_VDU1_2', 'UUB_VDU1_3', 'UUB_VDU2_1',
   'UUB_VDU2_2'], dtype=object)
```

while to see the remaining part I have to remove the last concatenation. How would you solve it?

Comment: Please fix the error in your code: NameError: name 'vm_num' is not defined on line 6

Comment: Also the title *"not able to properly divide strings in a series"* doesn't tell us anything at all. *"split series of '_'-separated string into variable number of fields, filling missing fields"* would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the two cases separately using Boolean indexing, where you check if `vdu_num` is NaN or not

```
df.loc[~vdu_num.isna(), 'vm']=df['Unit'].str.cat(unit_num, sep="_").str.cat(vdu_num, sep="_")
df.loc[vdu_num.isna(), 'vm']=df['Unit'].str.cat(unit_num, sep="_")
```

produces

```
    resource              Node    Unit    unit_num      vdu_num  vm
--  --------------------  ------  ------  ----------  ---------  ----------
 0  MTUG1_ABO_DPP_1       MTUG1   DPP     1                 nan  DPP_1
 1  MTUG1_ABO_DPP_2       MTUG1   DPP     2                 nan  DPP_2
 2  MTUG1_ABO_DPP_3       MTUG1   DPP     3                 nan  DPP_3
 3  MTUG1_ABO_DPP_4       MTUG1   DPP     4                 nan  DPP_4
 4  MTUG1_ABO_DPP_5       MTUG1   DPP     5                 nan  DPP_5
 5  MTUG1_ABO_DPU_1       MTUG1   DPU     1                 nan  DPU_1
 6  MTUG1_ABO_DPU_2       MTUG1   DPU     2                 nan  DPU_2
 7  MTUG1_ABO_DPU_3       MTUG1   DPU     3                 nan  DPU_3
 8  MTUG1_ABO_UUB_VDU1_1  MTUG1   UUB     VDU1                1  UUB_VDU1_1
 9  MTUG1_ABO_UUB_VDU1_2  MTUG1   UUB     VDU1                2  UUB_VDU1_2
10  MTUG1_ABO_UUB_VDU1_3  MTUG1   UUB     VDU1                3  UUB_VDU1_3
11  MTUG1_ABO_UUB_VDU2_1  MTUG1   UUB     VDU2                1  UUB_VDU2_1
12  MTUG1_ABO_UUB_VDU2_2  MTUG1   UUB     VDU2                2  UUB_VDU2_2
```

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly! What does that character ~ mean?

Comment: Glad it helped! The character '~' in Boolean indexing means 'not'. So the first line selects rows where 'vdu_num is **not** NaN'. Consider accepting the answer per the guidelines https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: seems to not correspond to the desired output.

Comment: @PierreD agree -- went by the OP's code for the case that *did* work which was somewhat inconsistent with the output provided.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your split (do it once), and then also use `where` to take `unit_num` or `vdu_num` depending on whichever is non null:

```
df2 = (
    df['resource']
    .str.split('_', expand=True)[[0, 2, 3, 4]]
    .set_axis('Node Unit unit_num vdu_num'.split(), axis=1)
)
df2['vm'] = df2['Unit'].str.cat(
    df2['unit_num'].where(df2['vdu_num'].isnull(), df2['vdu_num']), sep='_')
```

Or, if you prefer to overwrite your original `df`:

```
df = pd.concat([
    df['resource'],
    df['resource']
    .str.split('_', expand=True)[[0, 2, 3, 4]]
    .set_axis('Node Unit unit_num vdu_num'.split(), axis=1)
], axis=1)
df['vm'] = df['Unit'].str.cat(
    df['unit_num'].where(df['vdu_num'].isnull(), df['vdu_num']), sep='_')
```